# Записать не строку а число в гугл таблицк

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet

Всем привет.

Кто подскажет можно ли записать данные в гугл таблицу с указанием типа данных?
Использую библиотеку gspread и она записывает все значения как строку. А мне нужно записать число

Comment: можете привести пример кода, которы вы используете потому что [документация](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#cell-object) не показывает каких то  ощутимых ограничений.

Comment: Вопрос можно закрыть gspread загружает все данные как строку не важно что туда ложить )

Comment: Если вы нашли ответ, было бы не плохо его вам оформить как ответ на свой вопрос. Кто -то, да, столкнется с этим вопросом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Gspread` загружает все данные как строку: не важно, какой тип данных был передан изначально